# IntelliJ Playframework sbt fails

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea, playframework-2.0, sbt

I am trying to install the Play framework in IntelliJ. According to guides online the only thing I need is IntelliJ Ultimate and the plugin Scala(with play 2 support).

I successfully created a project with

> New -> Project -> Scala -> Play 2

The IDE is now only stuck with the following message:

> SBT: Getting org.scala-sbt sbt 0.3.15.

There is no network activity, so it is not downloading anything.

How can I resolve this? I'm using OSX.

Comment: I experienced it several times too. Just be patient, it will take long time to get it.

Comment: Did you install any other software? From what i've read in the documentation i don't need to install the activator and SBT tools, because IntelliJ takes care of that. Or do i need to install these tools, and IntelliJ uses these tools?

Comment: You don't need to but I did. I prefer running sbt tasks from console.

Comment: I installed the Activator and created the project from the command line. Then i imported the project in IntelliJ and it is working perfect now :)